# Loading existing project in django

Tags: python, django

I have created a new project using DJANGO but when I run `manage.py runserver`, it points to the settings of my old project.

**Specific Details are given below**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\jaia\Desktop\Learn Django\MyLibrary>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found

Django version 1.4.2, using settings 'FirstBlog.settings'

Development server is running at ttp://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

**Explanation**

I want runserver to use MyLibrary.settings (New Project) but instead it uses FirstBlog.settings (Old Project).

Can you please instruct me how to changes the settings.

Comment: are you on Windows or ...?

Comment: no one asked but... "how did you create this new project?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the environment varible:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyLibrary.settings
python manage.py runserver
```

Or append `--settings` like:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=MyLibrary.settings
```

The [details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) - Django docs.

Answer (score 1):

Look in manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FirstBlog.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

change this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyLibrary.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```